# Windows 10 batch echoes entire file, does not run commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I'm trying to run a .bat file that installs some python dependencies, downloads a python script and then runs said script. Since I plan on sending the file to someone who is not exactly code-savvy, I included some echo commands to tell him what is being done. 
When I went to test running the file, it just echoed the entire thing back to me without doing any of the commmands. Below is my abridged batch file:

```
@echo off 
echo "Installing dependencies..." 
 
python -m pip install -U requests 

echo "Done!" 

echo "Downloading script..." 

bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.py" "%CD%\script.py" 

echo "Done downloading the script!" 

echo "Now let's run that sucker." 

python script.py
```

And this is the output:

```
C:\Users\maxhe\Desktop>my.bat
off echo "Installing dependencies..."  python -m pip install -U requests echo "Done!" echo "Downloading script..." bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.py" "C:\Users\maxhe\Desktop\script.py" echo "Done downloading the script!" echo "Now let's run that sucker." python script.py
```

Running each of the commands separately in the cmd console works fine, but if I try using the .bat file, I just get my entire input back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add everything on a single line in the batch file? it should not be, it should be line for line like you have add here on the question.

Comment: Everything is on a new line, even leaving one blank line between each instruction. Leaving out the blank lines gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run everything in a single like like this from a batch file. It should be a command per line. So copy the below, as is and paste into your `batch-file` Do not change anything.

```
@echo off
echo "Installing dependencies..."  
python -m pip install -U requests 
echo "Done!" 
echo "Downloading script..." 
bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.py" "%CD%\script.py" 
echo "Done downloading the script!" 
echo "Now let's run that sucker." 
python script.py
```

**EDIT**

copy the below code, open `cmd` then right click in `cmd` to paste the code. Once done, there will be a `yours.cmd` on your desktop.. run it like you did `my.bat` from `cmd`

```
cd /d "%userprofile%\Desktop"
(echo echo "Installing dependencies..."  
echo python -m pip install -U requests 
echo echo "Done!" 
echo echo "Downloading script..." 
echo bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.py" "%CD%\script.py" 
echo echo "Done downloading the script!" 
echo echo "Now let's run that sucker." 
echo python script.py
)>yours.cmd
echo done
call yours.cmd
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, but if you look at my source file (upper codeblock), everything is on a new line, even leaving one blank between each instruction. Leaving out the blank lines gives the same result.

Comment: hold a sec for me please.

Comment: That worked, but it seems like a bit of a hack. I'm wondering what caused it in the first place. Thank you regardless!

Comment: Well, it is not a hack, I pretty much just gave you a command to create the file for you. As for why, I do not know, what editor do you use to create the files?

Comment: I used notepad++

Comment: @Chippy: probably an issue with the encoding (ASCII vs. Unicode, BOM vs. plain) and/or line endings (Unix-style vs. Windows-style). Notepad++ is very flexible in these points. Check the settings.